# GAM with only Categorical/Logical

Tags: r, factors, gam

I'm currently trying to use a GAM to calculate a rough estimation of expected goals model based purely on the commentary data from ESPN. However, all the data is either a categorical variable or a logical vector, so I'm not sure if there's a way to smooth, or if I should just use the factor names.

Here are my variables:

- shot_where (factor): shot location (e.g. right side of the box)
- assist_class (factor): type of assist (cross, through ball, pass)
- follow_corner (logical): whether the shot follows a corner
- shot_with (factor): right foot, left food, header
- follow_set_piece (logical): whether the shot follows a set piece

I think I should just use the formula as just the variable names.

```
    model <- bam(is_goal ~ shot_where + assist_class + follow_set_piece + shot_where + follow_corner + shot_where:shot_with, family = "binomial", method = "REML")
```

The shot_where and shot_with would incorporate any interactions between these two varaibles.

However, I was told I could smooth factor variables as well using the below structure.

```
    model <- bam(is_goal ~ s(shot_where, bs = 'fs') + s(assist_class, bs = 'fs') + as.logical(follow_set_piece) +
              as.logical(follow_corner) + s(shot_with, bs = 'fs'), data = model_data, family = "binomial", method = "REML")
```

This worked for creating a model, but I want to make sure this is a correct method of building the model. I've yet to see any information on using only factor/logical variables in a GAM model, so I thought it was worth asking.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have categorical covariates then you aren't fitting a GAM, whether you fit the model with `gam()`, `bam()`, or something else.

What you are doing when you pass factor variables to `s()` using the `fs` basis like this

```r
s(f, bs = 'fs')`
```

is creating a *random intercept* for each level of the factor `f`.

There's no smoothing going on here at all; the model is simply exploiting the equivalence of the Bayesian view of smoothing with random effects.

Given that none of your covariates could reasonably be considered random in the sense of a mixed effects model then the only justification for doing what you're doing might be as a computational trick.

Your first model is just a simple GLM (note the typo in the formula as `shot_where` is repeated twice in the formula.)

It's not clear to me why you are using `bam()` to fit this model; you're loosing computational efficiency that `bam()` provides by using `method = 'REML'`; it should be `'fREML'` for `bam()` models. But as there is no smoothness selection going on in the first model you'd likely be better off using `glm()` to fit that model. If the issue is large sample sizes, there are several packages that can fit GLMs to large data, for example *biglm* and it's `bigglm()` function.

In the second model there is no smoothing going on but there is penalisation which is shrinking the estimates for the random intercepts toward zero. You're likely to get better performance on big data using the *lme4* package or TMB and the *glmmTMB* package to fit what is a GLMM.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a theoretical question than about R, but let me provide a brief answer.  Essentially, the most flexible model you could estimate would be one where you used the variables as factors.  It also produces a model that is reasonably easily interpreted - where each coefficient gives you the expected difference in y between the reference level and the level represented by the dummy regressor.

Smoothing splines try to strike the appropriate bias-variance tradeoff.  If you've got lots of data and relatively few categories in the categorical variables, there will be no real loss in efficiency for including all of the dummy regressors representing the categories and the bias will also be as small as possible.  To the extent that the smoothing spline model is different from the one treating everything as factors, it is likely inducing bias without a corresponding increase in efficiency.  If it were me, I would stick with a model that treats all of the categorical variables as factors.

Comment: You can't estimate smooth functions of categorical variables; if you do as you suggest or what the OP did (minus the `fs` basis) this model is just a GLM. There's no penalization going, no smoothing, just a plain old GLM.

Comment: @GavinSimpson True, though you could make them numeric in R and then do some minimal smoothing over those values.  I think this would work better for ordinal than nominal variables, though I think the regular GLM approach is the way to go.